# customize color usercolors theme

Tags: beamer, color

I've already read the topic about the customization of colours in beamer (in this forum and on google..) but I didn't find any solution!

My aims is to set the basic colours of the Madrid beamers themes changing from the default blue to the Rgb = {0,120,174} .
I thought that was a simple thing but I didn't come out ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{1,0,0} 

\usetheme{Madrid}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```